# Tensorflow: Count number of examples in a TFRecord file -- without using deprecated `tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator`

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

**Please read post before marking Duplicate**:

I was looking for an efficient way to count the number of examples in a TFRecord file of images. Since a TFRecord file does not save any metadata about the file itself, the user has to loop through the file in order to calculate this information.

There are a few different questions on StackOverflow that answer this question. **The problem is that all of them seem to use the DEPRECATED [`tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/tf_record_iterator) command, so this is not a stable solution.** Here is the sample of existing posts:

[Obtaining total number of records from .tfrecords file in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472139/obtaining-total-number-of-records-from-tfrecords-file-in-tensorflow)

[Number of examples in each tfrecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799007/number-of-examples-in-each-tfrecord)

[Number of examples in each tfrecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799007/number-of-examples-in-each-tfrecord)

So I was wondering if there was a way to count the number of records using the new Dataset API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [`reduce`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#reduce) method listed under the `Dataset` class. They give an example of counting records using the method:

```
# generate the dataset (batch size and repeat must be 1, maybe avoid dataset manipulation like map and shard)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(5) 
# count the examples by reduce
cnt = ds.reduce(np.int64(0), lambda x, _: x + 1)

## produces 5
```

Don't know whether this method is faster than the @krishnab's for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following code to work without the deprecated command. Hopefully this will help others.

Using the Dataset API I setup and iterator and then loop over it. Not sure if this is the fastest, but it works. MAKE SURE THE BATCH SIZE AND REPEAT ARE SET TO 1, otherwise the code will return the number of batches and not the number of examples in the dataset.

```
count_test = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('testing.tfrecord')
count_test = count_test.map(_parse_image_function)
count_test = count_test.repeat(1)
count_test = count_test.batch(1)
test_counter = count_test.make_one_shot_iterator()

c = 0
for ex in test_counter:
    c += 1
f"There are {c} testing records"
```

This seemed to work reasonably well even on a relatively large file.

Comment: Error `'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'make_one_shot_iterator'` bumped out. The same without `.make_one_shot_iterator` has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me using TensorFlow version 2.1 (using the code found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58413391/85248)):

```
def count_tfrecord_examples(
        tfrecords_dir: str,
) -> int:
    """
    Counts the total number of examples in a collection of TFRecord files.

    :param tfrecords_dir: directory that is assumed to contain only TFRecord files
    :return: the total number of examples in the collection of TFRecord files
        found in the specified directory
    """

    count = 0
    for file_name in os.listdir(tfrecords_dir):
        tfrecord_path = os.path.join(tfrecords_dir, file_name)
        count += sum(1 for _ in tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecord_path))

    return count
```